# invalid reference to FROM-clause entry with CTE

Tags: postgresql, common-table-expression

I'm trying to write a query to generate time periods but am getting the error:

```
ERROR: invalid reference to FROM-clause entry for table "prop"
Hint: There is an entry for table "prop", but it cannot be referenced from this part of the query.
Position: 346
```

The query is:

```
WITH prop AS (SELECT p.stagger, p.tariff FROM core_property p WHERE p.id = 1)
SELECT day + (hour.a * INTERVAL '1 hour') AS time,
       day + (hour.b * INTERVAL '1 hour') AS timeEnd
FROM prop,
     GENERATE_SERIES(date '2022-05-18' + prop.stagger, date '2022-05-20', '1 day'::INTERVAL) day,
     (SELECT UNNEST(CASE
                        WHEN prop.tariff = 'Economy 7' THEN ARRAY [0,12,18]
                        WHEN prop.tariff = 'Economy 10' THEN ARRAY [0] END) a,
             UNNEST(CASE
                        WHEN prop.tariff = 'Economy 7' THEN ARRAY [5,13,20]
                        WHEN prop.tariff = 'Economy 10' THEN ARRAY [7] END) b) hour;
```

I have a version of this query that almost works but generates duplicates and is ugly:

```
SELECT day + p.stagger + (CASE
                              WHEN p.tariff = 'Economy 7' THEN e7.a
                              WHEN p.tariff = 'Economy 10' THEN e10.a END) * INTERVAL '1 hour' AS time,
       day + p.stagger + (CASE
                              WHEN p.tariff = 'Economy 7' THEN e7.b
                              WHEN p.tariff = 'Economy 10' THEN e10.b END) * INTERVAL '1 hour' AS timeEnd

FROM GENERATE_SERIES(date '2022-05-18', date '2022-05-20', '1 day'::INTERVAL) day,
     (SELECT UNNEST(ARRAY [0,13,20]) a, UNNEST(ARRAY [5,16,22]) b) e10,
     (SELECT UNNEST(ARRAY [0]) a, UNNEST(ARRAY [7]) b) e7,
     (SELECT p.stagger, p.tariff FROM core_property p WHERE p.id = 1) p;
```

The result is this when p.tariff = 'Economy 7', but there should only be one entry for each day:

```
+---------------------------------+---------------------------------+
|time                             |timeend                          |
+---------------------------------+---------------------------------+
|2022-05-18 00:15:00.000000 +00:00|2022-05-18 07:15:00.000000 +00:00|
|2022-05-18 00:15:00.000000 +00:00|2022-05-18 07:15:00.000000 +00:00|
|2022-05-18 00:15:00.000000 +00:00|2022-05-18 07:15:00.000000 +00:00|
|2022-05-19 00:15:00.000000 +00:00|2022-05-19 07:15:00.000000 +00:00|
|2022-05-19 00:15:00.000000 +00:00|2022-05-19 07:15:00.000000 +00:00|
|2022-05-19 00:15:00.000000 +00:00|2022-05-19 07:15:00.000000 +00:00|
|2022-05-20 00:15:00.000000 +00:00|2022-05-20 07:15:00.000000 +00:00|
|2022-05-20 00:15:00.000000 +00:00|2022-05-20 07:15:00.000000 +00:00|
|2022-05-20 00:15:00.000000 +00:00|2022-05-20 07:15:00.000000 +00:00|
+---------------------------------+---------------------------------+
```

When p.tariff = 'Economy 10' then the result is right:

```
+---------------------------------+---------------------------------+
|time                             |timeend                          |
+---------------------------------+---------------------------------+
|2022-05-18 00:15:00.000000 +00:00|2022-05-18 05:15:00.000000 +00:00|
|2022-05-18 13:15:00.000000 +00:00|2022-05-18 16:15:00.000000 +00:00|
|2022-05-18 20:15:00.000000 +00:00|2022-05-18 22:15:00.000000 +00:00|
|2022-05-19 00:15:00.000000 +00:00|2022-05-19 05:15:00.000000 +00:00|
|2022-05-19 13:15:00.000000 +00:00|2022-05-19 16:15:00.000000 +00:00|
|2022-05-19 20:15:00.000000 +00:00|2022-05-19 22:15:00.000000 +00:00|
|2022-05-20 00:15:00.000000 +00:00|2022-05-20 05:15:00.000000 +00:00|
|2022-05-20 13:15:00.000000 +00:00|2022-05-20 16:15:00.000000 +00:00|
|2022-05-20 20:15:00.000000 +00:00|2022-05-20 22:15:00.000000 +00:00|
+---------------------------------+---------------------------------+
```

I'm not sure if I really need a CTE but it seemed like the only way to use prop.tariff and prop.stagger in the FROM clause.

Comment: If you provide some sample data along with the expected results based on that sample data, your chances that you'll get correct answer will become very high. If in addition to that you also explain in plain words the required logic that would be even better. Right now the required logic is not clear to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A subquery in a FROM/JOIN list cannot reference other tables of the FROM/JOIN list, unless the join is declared as `lateral`.  So declare it as LATERAL.

```
WITH prop AS (SELECT p.stagger, p.tariff FROM core_property p WHERE p.id = 1)
SELECT day + (hour.a * INTERVAL '1 hour') AS time,
       day + (hour.b * INTERVAL '1 hour') AS timeEnd
FROM prop,
     GENERATE_SERIES(date '2022-05-18' + prop.stagger, date '2022-05-20', '1 day'::INTERVAL) day, 
     LATERAL (SELECT UNNEST(CASE
                        WHEN prop.tariff = 'Economy 7' THEN ARRAY [0,12,18]
                        WHEN prop.tariff = 'Economy 10' THEN ARRAY [0] END) a,
             UNNEST(CASE
                        WHEN prop.tariff = 'Economy 7' THEN ARRAY [5,13,20]
                        WHEN prop.tariff = 'Economy 10' THEN ARRAY [7] END) b) hour;
```

An exception to this is a bare set-returning function used in the FROM/JOIN list, which is implicitly treated as lateral. Which is why the `generate_series(...) doesn't throw the same error.